# Nested resources and on: collection don't do what I expect from them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

My routes.rb

```
   resources :users do
      resources :tags, on: :collection
      get :some_page, on: :collection
    end
```

and rake routes

```
users/:user_id/tags(.:format) --- tags#index
users/:user_id/tags(.:format) --- tags#create
users/:user_id/tags/new(.:format) --- tags#new
//......
users/some_page(.:format) --- users#some_page
```

and there are 2 controllers: `UsersController` and `UsersTagsController`.

I want the routes for tags to be:

```
users/tags(.:format) --- users_tags#index
users/tags(.:format) --- users_tags#create
users/tags/new(.:format) --- users_tags#new
//............
```

Why don't they look like this and how do I fix this?

Comment: Then you should use namespacing as @maerka suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's because `:on` only work with single routes. Try this instead:

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    resources :tags
  end
end
```

Comment: but the controllers and actions remain the same as before.

Answer (score 0):

You should name your controller `Users::TagsController`
And then in routes:

```
namespace :users do
  resources :tags
end
```